# How does speckle imaging fit in to 21st century high resolution imaging from ground based observatories?

Tags: observational-astronomy, photography, interferometry

Phys.org's [Astronomers uncover evidence that there could be many more Earth-sized planets than previously thought](https://phys.org/news/2021-06-astronomers-uncover-evidence-earth-sized-planets.html) references [Speckle Observations of TESS Exoplanet Host Stars. II. Stellar Companions at 1-1000 AU and Implications for Small Planet Detection](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.13354) who's abstract begins:

> We present high angular resolution imaging observations of 517 host stars of TESS exoplanet candidates **using the ‘Alopeke and Zorro speckle cameras at Gemini North and South.** The sample consists mainly of bright F, G, K stars at distances of less than 500 pc. Our speckle observations span angular resolutions of ∼20 mas out to 1.2 arcsec, yielding spatial resolutions of <10 to 500 AU for most stars, and our contrast limits can detect companion stars 5−9 magnitudes fainter than the primary at optical wavelengths.

I remember the excitement about [Speckle Imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speckle_imaging) in the early 1980's but didn't realize that it was still an actively used technique 40 years later.

**Question:** How does speckle imaging fit in to 21st century high resolution imaging from ground based observatories? Is it what you do when you can't get time on an adaptive-optics equipped instrument, or need to image at shorter wavelengths than that technique works for? Did they drag these out of a closet for this observation campaign or is this still an actively used technique in the 2020's?